# Referenced objects are still loaded while FetchType.LAZY enabled

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"suburbs", "upCities"})
class City {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "suburbs", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<City> uppers = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @BatchSize(size = 5)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<City> suburbs = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public int compareTo(City o) {
        return publicId.compareTo(o.getId());
    }
}

class CityService {
  public List<City> findAll() {
        return dao.findAll().stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

The `findAll` method still loads all referenced entity (suburbs and uppers) even I set Lazy fetch.

In the hibernate log, there is a `select suburbs` query, but there is no `select uppers` query.

I have no idea how does this happen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This is because Hibernate has no other way of knowing whether to assign a null or a Proxy to this variable. What you are seeing may be proxy objects.

Use  `optional = false` and try. This optional trick does not work on every of Hibernate.

Comment: `optional = false` means that there must be a referenced entity? But the Set might be empty.